# sbt runmain does not find class

Tags: sbt

I have a function that I'm running with `sbt runMain`. I was able to get this working previously, but some changes in the project means it's no longer working, but I can't quite understand it.

When I run
`sbt "runMain com.example.projects.data.CallMe"` I get:

```
[error] (Compile / runMain) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
com.example.projects.data.CallMe.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

But in the SBT console, this works:

```
import com.example.projects.data.*
CallMe.main(List())
```

This succeeds. How would I be able to debug this?

Versions:

- Scala 3.1.2
- Sbt: 1.6.2